# I want to add the numbers in all the columns in dynamic added tableview

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I am making a dynamic table with 5 columns... I want when I click the total button I get the sum of all the amounts previous of one particular column added to one text view... like in the picture I want to add the total amounts of each row to the below text view.... please help me.. I have tried many things but none of them is making a logic to me

```
 et8 = new EditText(this);
        et9 = new EditText(this);
        et10 = new EditText(this);
        et7.setText("");
        et8.setText("");
        et9.setText("");
        et10.setText("");
        et6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext3);
        et6.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        et6.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        et7.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext3);
        et7.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        et7.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        et8.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext3);
        et8.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        et8.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        et9.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext3);
        et9.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        et9.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        et10.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext3);
        et10.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        et10.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        tr1.addView(et6);
        tr1.addView(et7);
        tr1.addView(et8);
        tr1.addView(et9);
        tr1.addView(et10);
        t1.addView(tr1);
        try {
            for (i = 0; i <= t1.getChildCount()-1; i++)
                qty.setText(String.valueOf(i));


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "failed to add qty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        et9.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                try {
                    int i, j;
                    int mul;
                    i = Integer.parseInt(et8.getText().toString());
                    j = Integer.parseInt(et9.getText().toString());
                    mul = i * j;

                    et10.setText("" + (Integer.toString(mul)));

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please calculate before adding row", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });


        final Snackbar snbr = Snackbar.make(view,"Row added",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
        snbr.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(view.getContext(),R.color.colorsnac1));
        snbr.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.snactxt));
        snbr.show();
        snbr.setAction("Dismiss", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t1.removeView(tr1);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

[image: Image Here]

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you should really be using a RecyclerView rather than trying to insert each row manually. Then, you could create a global ArrayList variable that stores the prices in the Price column. Each price EditText gets a TextChangedListener that updates its corresponding element in the ArrayList. The TextChangedListeners also iterate through the ArrayList, check if each value is a number, and if so add it to the price total and then display the newly computed total.

Answer (score 0):

Their are many ways to do it

1)  one way is while adding view to viewgroup set id or index

```
int tablerow = 1;

.....
tr1.setId(tablerow);
```

use this id and value of mul store in `hashmap`
use additional variable to store value of 'mul' in for loop

while removing view in use view's id that is index 
you can decrease total amount by searching view's index in `hashmap`